# autocomplete friends list on socialengine

Tags: autocomplete, socialengine

how can I use the auto completer used in compose message on socialengine within a page with 2 different text boxes?

I know we could use it with a textbox with id 'to' to get that autocomplete work. But How do I use that same auto complete on another textbox with id eventto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the id on request (to to toe here  )

```
new Autocompleter.Request.JSON('toe', '<?php echo $this->url(array('module' => 'user', 'controller' => 'friends', 'action' => 'suggest'), 'default', true) ?>', {
        'minLength': 1,
        'delay' : 250,
        'selectMode': 'pick',
        'autocompleteType': 'message',
        'multiple': false,
        'className': 'message-autosuggest',
        'filterSubset' : true,
        'tokenFormat' : 'object',
        'tokenValueKey' : 'label',
        'injectChoice': function(token){
          if(token.type == 'user'){
            var choice = new Element('li', {
              'class': 'autocompleter-choices',
              'html': token.photo,
              'id':token.label
            });
            new Element('div', {
              'html': this.markQueryValue(token.label),
              'class': 'autocompleter-choice'
            }).inject(choice);
            this.addChoiceEvents(choice).inject(this.choices);
            choice.store('autocompleteChoice', token);
          }
          else {
            var choice = new Element('li', {
              'class': 'autocompleter-choices friendlist',
              'id':token.label
            });
            new Element('div', {
              'html': this.markQueryValue(token.label),
              'class': 'autocompleter-choice'
            }).inject(choice);
            this.addChoiceEvents(choice).inject(this.choices);
            choice.store('autocompleteChoice', token);
          }

        }
      , onPush : function(){
        }
      });
```

Comment: How can i get all user's list instead of friends only ?